# How to implement a conditional pop concurrency-friendly in Redis?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, nosql, redis

I am building something like a delay-line: one process RPUSHes objects into a list, another LPOPs them out in the same order.

The trick is that objects should only be popped from the list one hour after they have been added. I could use a time-stamp for that. The delay is the same for all items and never changes.

Now how to I implement the pop in a concurrency-friendly way (so that it still works when several workers access that list)? I could take out an item, check the timestamp and put it back into the list if it's still too early. But if several workers do that simultaneously, it may mess up the order of items. I could check the first item and only pop it if it's due. But another worker might have popped it then so I pop the wrong one.

Should I use the WATCH command? How? Should I use sorted sets instead of a list? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the item back in the list after checking it won't mess up the ordering enough to matter - by having any sort of concurrency you accept that the order won't be strictly defined. However, that approach won't be particularly efficient as you can't check the timestamp without some processing of the item.

With the scripting build you could implement a conditional pop command for sorted sets, though I don't think that is the easiest solution.

There are a couple of ways to implement basic scheduling using multiple lists:

- Add tasks to a sorted set and have a single worker responsible for moving them from the sorted set to a list that multiple workers access with pop.
- Have a list for each minute, and have the workers read from past lists. You can minimize the number of lists checked by using another key that tracks the oldest non-empty queue.

Comment: Messing up the order DOES matter in the case where an item which is due gets swapped with one that is not due yet. In the worst case, it can delay the due item by another hour.
But the list-for-each-minute idea sounds interesting. I will think more about that

Comment: True, though if you have enough items getting added to need multiple workers that worst case is extremely unlikely. If necessary you could use a combination of LRANGE and LPOP to check if there are any due items before removing one for processing.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest using a sorted set.  Entries go into the zset with the normal identifier as key and a Unix-style timestamp as the score.  Make the timestamps the date+time after which each entry is ready for parsing.  Workers do a `ZPOP`, which isn't a built-in but can be emulated with:

```
MULTI
ZRANGE <key> 0 0 WITHSCORES
ZREMRANGEBYRANK <key> 0 0
EXEC
```

Capture the results of the `ZRANGE` and you have the element with the lowest score at the time, already removed from the set, with its score.  Put it back if it's not valid yet with a `ZADD <key> <score> <item>`.

Comment: Nice idea. Will it work with high amount of concurrent requests? E.g: will the zrange and zremrangebyrank be executed like a transaction without commands from concurrent requests between them causing it to return one key and delete another.

Comment: Yes, it will work. That's the entire purpose of MULTI and EXEC. They basically wrap commands in a transaction.